# Image Stretched using Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I am using `Picasso` library for loading image from service. Its working fine. But While `scroll` the image down and again i scroll up, image was Stretched using `recyclerview` with `swiperefresh` layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bg_image_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="175dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bg_image"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"            />

    </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/img_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_below="@id/bg_image_layout"/>   

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In my adapter class:

```
Picasso.with(context)
                   .load(items.get(position).getBgImage())
                   .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                   .fit()
                   .centerCrop()
                   .into(shopViewHolder.bgImage);
```

Can any one can help me?.. where i did wrong here..

Answer (score 1):

You used `.fit()`. That will fit the image into your `shopViewHolder.bgImage` (stretching if necessary). You can always ensure that the image remains a certain size with `.resize(width, height)`. You can then use `.centerCrop()` and `.centerInside()` to control how that will handle overlap.

You will need  to use a different method if you wish a different type of result.

Comment: i need to display the image with out stretching, so which one i have to use for resolve this issue?..

Comment: You could try removing `.fit()` and `.centerCrop()` and instead use `.centerInside()`. You can set also `.resize(int, int)`. I haven't tested, but that should do what you need it to do. More information about maintaining aspect ratio here: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/226